# MVC - CSS for a specific view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have changed my css sheet for my entire site and it works great. The change has to do with the background color of rows in tables. Although it does what I want, there is one view that I would like to be exempt from this alteration. Is there a way to exclude this view from the change or create a new css sheet for this specific view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would come up with a CSS styling strategy. The goal should be to minimize CSS and overrides. Also, having an extra CSS file for just one page will cause an extra HTTP round trip to get the resource. My recommendation is to stick extra CSS classes on this view. Then, override precisely the styles that you need in your global CSS styles.

Comment: thanks for the response. I apologize, but I am fairly new to MVC and very new to styling. How would I go about the method that you explained? Do I simply add something to the view to override certain aspects of the CSS?

Comment: Yup, you can add specific CSS class attribute to the things you need to override. It should be kept as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution which ended up being much easier than I expected. Since I am very new to using CSS and HTML I was unaware of the style tag. However, that is what I was looking for. For anybody looking at this in the future, just use:

```
<style>
    (CSS that you would like to override)
</style>
```